# Composer require installation profile constraint match error

Tags: 8, composer

I am trying to download this install profile https://github.com/UH-StudentServices/student_guide

I added it to composer.json like this

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:UH-StudentServices/student_guide.git"
        }
    ],
```

Then I did `composer require` and I got following error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires uh-studentservices/student_guide ^1.62 -> satisfiable by uh-studentservices/student_guide[v1.62].
    - uh-studentservices/student_guide v1.62 requires drupal/block_access dev-8.x-1.x#1cd59ba6856c897afae2551feaa8e6b7f312489c -> found drupal/block_access[dev-1.x, 1.0.0-alpha1, 1.0.0-beta1, 1.x-dev (alias of dev-1.x)] but it does not match the constraint.
```

I know that the module version should be dev-1.x and not dev-8.x-1.x. I am wondering what should I do. May be I can clone the install profile and edit the composer.json, but How can I include it in composer.json locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to add to the `repositories` key in composer.json *all* of the [repositories specified by the project](https://github.com/UH-StudentServices/student_guide/blob/develop/composer.json#L89) because it seems some are not registered with Packagist.

```json
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org/"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/larowlan/block_access"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "rubaxa/sortable",
                "version": "v1.4.0",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/archive/1.4.0.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/UH-StudentServices/video_embed_unitube"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/UH-StudentServices/uh_courses_embed"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:UH-StudentServices/student_guide.git"
        }
    ],
```

Notice that although the profile will install, you will see:

```
 Cannot apply patch 2795115-6-and-2860399-1 (patches/google_analytics_reports.patch)!
```

That is because there is a patches directory in the parent project that you will not have. I think that if you copy the patches to your own project, the patch may apply.

Comment: Now I am getting following error `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires uh-studentservices/student_guide ^1.62 -> satisfiable by uh-studentservices/student_guide[v1.62].
    - uh-studentservices/student_guide v1.62 requires rubaxa/sortable 1.4.0 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.`

Comment: This is what I did `"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:UH-StudentServices/student_guide.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/larowlan/block_access"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],`

Comment: If you are specifying repositories, and still need to use the official one, Packagist, then you also require this one:

{
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }

It is there by default in the official Drupal starter project.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error

Comment: I suppose the only way forward is for you to post a composer.json that reproduces this.

Comment: Here is my composer.json https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mabkyc507qia80/composer.json?dl=0

Comment: That ^ composer.json file works for me. There must be something missing from the steps to reproduce above. What are the arguments to `composer require` that fail?

Comment: Oh, I see: `composer require uh-studentservices/student_guide` fails. You require *all* the repositories specified by the composer.json in uh-studentservices/student_guide, not only some. I will update the answer.

Comment: Under patches folder, there is a sql folder. What is it about?

Comment: The `composer require` command worked thanks a lot. However, at the end I see this `Not scaffolding files for uh-studentservices/student_guide, because it is not listed in the element 'extra.drupal-scaffold.allowed-packages' in the root-level composer.json file.`

Comment: I've answered the question. Please accept my answer. Configuring drupal-scaffold, which is well-documented (https://github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold), is a different question.